# Cache problem after sending a html-form

Tags: php, html, caching

in some part of my webpage i allow my users to change their profile picture. This is made simple by a form with the element `<input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar" />`. After they upload the photo a php script is called were all the image checking and processing is made. When everything is ok, the previous user image is deleted and changed by the new one (with the same name) and then the user is redirected to their profile page.

The problem is, when the user change his picture, the firts time he goes to his profile page (when is redirected by the upload script) the picture is not the new one, is a cached copy of the old one, after a few f5 (reloads) the new image is showed.

A while ago a have a similar problem with an rss parser i made in php, if i call the url feed sometimes instead of a new version of the feed, i got a cached version. I solved this problem just by generating a ramdom number every time i needed the feed and then adding it to the url like; www.page.com/thefeed.rss?var=#ramdom_number

But, i really dont want to implement this "solution" because is unprofessional and my users will see the url with that parameter.

This is a resume of the upload operation:

**profile.php?i=mycv** : In this page is all the user data included the actual profile picture and the form to upload a picture, the form makes a post call to image_handler.php

**image_handler.php** : Is a php script who process the image sended by *profile.php?i=mycv* and is everything is ok, the user is redirected to *profile.php?i=mycv*.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you working with the image, is it just stored in a directory, so you in effect call www.mydomain.com/profile/img00001.jpg or, is it in a database, or is the image a result of src=getprofilepic.php and held in a database etc? most likely if its done by a script, you just need to make sure you sent the headers to try and tell the browser and any proxy engines not to cache it

Comment: The image is call simply by www.mydomain.com/profile/img00001.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in profile.php

```
<?php
$act = $_GET["a"];

 if($a == "return"){
 header("location:profile.php?i=mycv");
 }
?>
```

And then change url in `image_handler.php` that it sends user to `profile.php?a=return` page instead of `profile.php?i=mycv`

If that does not work you can add like this: `<img src="http://someplace.com/someimage.png?<?php print time(); ?>">` then user cannot see the number part.

Comment: But OP definitely said that he don't want such a hack. :)

Comment: "and my users will see the url with that parameter."      
I answered that they cannot see when using the my script.

Comment: For the first approach - you replace random number with some other odd parameter. For the second approach - even worse, some weird numbers in the image src. Have you test your approaches?

Comment: When you insert some numbers after image url browser thinks it´s a new image and does not use cache for it.